# Recommendation for a low cost Windows 7 based web server machine

Tags: iis, windows-7

I'm looking to replace my current web server with something smaller and less noisy. There are a few requirements as it hosts an ASP.NET web site:

Windows 7 Professional running IIS & SQL Server 2008R2
Wireless internet connection
Quiet (the current machine makes an incredible racket)
Disc space does not need to be excessive
Small (this would be great, ideally if it could be mac mini size then I would be happy).
Low power consumption
Cheap!

I was thinking about a [Mini-ITX Zotac bundle](http://www.mini-itx.com/store/?c=53#ION-A-bundle). Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic as per the SU FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like an Asus eeeBox - http://is.gd/nl5EtK They are cheap and quiet. It would easily powerful enough to host a basic low-traffic website.